# Linux Assembly - Could not read symbols: File in wrong format

Tags: assembly, nasm, ld

I am trying to compile an asm program on a linux server. I am new to writing asm programs, but I follow my school's tutorial and do everything they say but it has no success.

Here is my hello.asm file.

```
    SECTION .data
msg:    db "Hello World",10
len:    equ $-msg
    SECTION .text
        global main
main:
    mov edx,len
    mov ecx,msg
    mov ebx,1
    mov eax,4
    int 0x80
    mov ebx,0
    mov eax,1
    int 0x80
```

I compile this file using the command line `nasm -f elf hello.asm` which works completely fine and generates an object file. The problem is, when I try `ld hello.o`, it says that it cannot read symbols in the file and the file is in the wrong format.

Can anyone help me and tell me how I can compile a .asm file so it can run?

Comment: What if you link with `gcc -o hello hello.o` ?

Comment: It gives me the same error and tells me ld has a return status of 1.

Comment: Try: `ld -e main -m elf_i386 hello.o` or `gcc -m32 hello.o`. What do `uname -smr; dpkg --print-architecture; dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` (command in one line) say?

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to link a elf32 object file with a 64-bit linker? In that case you can set an appropriate linker emulation by passing `-m <emulation>` to `ld` (where `<emulation>` is one of the names you get when you run `ld -V`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a similar problem today, as a result of mixed 32-bit and 64-bit libraries (which is why I happen to have come upon your question). `ld` will complain if you try to link libraries of different types.  On a 64-bit system, `ld` defaults to 64-bit.

To specify the type you should be able to specify `ld -m elf_i386` for 32-bit, or `gcc -m32`.  (Or `gcc -m32 -static -nostdlib` for a static binary).

If your asm source code is portable to 64-bit, you could assemble as 64-bit with `nasm -f elf64`.  But it can assemble but fault at runtime from truncating a pointer, or have system calls return errors instead of working because [the `int 0x80` ABI is purely 32-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087730/what-happens-if-you-use-the-32-bit-int-0x80-linux-abi-in-64-bit-code).

Comment: Re: your last line: x86_64 syscall numbers differ from x86.

Comment: thanks, I've clarified.

Comment: It's `-m elf_i386` for `ld`, or `gcc -m32 -static -nostdlib` for gcc.  And no, you shouldn't just build 32-bit asm source as 64-bit with `nasm -felf64`.  It may fail to assemble (on `push ebx` or whatever), or fault at runtime if you use `esp`, or silently fail if you truncate 64-bit address to 32-bit by passing them to [`int 0x80` 32-bit ABI system calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087730/what-happens-if-you-use-the-32-bit-int-0x80-linux-abi-in-64-bit-code)

Comment: works for me!!!